# Writing my own IScheduler to to manage threads, what should be the best way to do this?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I am using ReactiveUI's ReactiveCommand feature which is very cool and serves the purpose. The only issue I am having with that is, ReactiveCommand when instantiated needs an IScheduler implementation and currently it only provides two MainThreadScheduler and TaskPoolScheduler and they both allow creating of separate thread per ReactiveCommand instance which I cannot afford because my application has enormous amount of ReactiveCommand instances.

So I decided to have my own IScheduler implementation that I could pass to ReactiveCommand constructor and what I would like to do is have some sort of configurable MaxThread; which will not allow more than the MaxThread threads.

There are two ways I can think of as or right now

1. Whenever application starts, start those threads and put them in Wait state trying to remove Tasks from ActionBlock, When Schedule is called, add that Action object to ActionBlock instance.
2. Create and Destroy, basically same as 1 but once a task is complete, end the thread instead of keeping it alive.

Does anybody have any suggestion as to how we should accomplish this ? Any input, code-sample, link to articles or something on Github/Codeplex would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to start new threads on long running tasks on the default scheduler then you can just use the default scheduler with the `ISchedulerLongRunning` optimisation disabled like so:

```
Scheduler.Default.DisableOptimizations(typeof(ISchedulerLongRunning));
```

Things like `ObserveOn` will create a new thread for each subscription if you don't do this

Answer (score 1):

So why do you not want to use the DefaultScheduler, which will kick out to a ThreadPool for you?

Also, if internally something is calling `ScheduleLongRunning()`, are you sure that this is what you want anyway? It seems like you could be introducing convoys and thread contention which is a complex domain to work in.

Maybe what you are actually looking to do is to either

1. Prime your thread pool so you dont get pauses when it needs to add threads to it
2. Create a better concurrency design for you application. If you have 80 things all scheduling form the UI at once, it sounds like something is not quite right.

I imagine Paul will have some insight?

Comment: ReactiveCommand's constructor causes ScheduleLongRunning() call which creates a new thread and put it to Wait state. I have 1 ReactiveCommand for each row of a Grid and I have 40+ rows. Not only ReactiveCommand's constructor is causing a new thread to be created for its action, but also a thread for Observing exceptions. So 2 threads per reactive command.... And no this is not what I want because as soon as my application hits the 80 threads mark, it get Out of Memory Exception thrown.

Comment: May be I should share 1 command instance among multiple grid rows and pass the Row Identification information to the command parameter or something.

Comment: Sharing a single Command instance is a common thing to do, so in this case that could be good. I cant see any code in the `ReactiveCommand` code that calls `ScheduleLongRunning()`, only calls to `ObserveOn` and `ScheduledSubject<T>` ctor which then just calls `ObserveOn`. Where does the `ScheduleLongRunning()` get called?

Comment: I have Rx and RxUI code... I am referencing projects... Its inside Platform specific Abstraction Layer implementation....There is an internal class called ScheduledObserver who's constructor is calling  _longRunning = _scheduler.AsLongRunning() which is basically an extension over my custom scheduler that returns a new ISchedulerLongRunning instance.... You either will have to go through the code; ther is no easy explanation... If you like I can send you a sample application code.

Comment: Sure I understand that. However still a call to `_scheduler.AsLongRunning()` is not the same as calling `ScheduleLongRunning()`. Is your implementation* of `IScheduler` contructing a thread when this is called? -->* Why would you create your own `IScheduler`?!

Comment: Here is the sample code without my own scheduler, see the enormous amount of threads it is creating. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy5hd3mpokusmjp/ReactiveUIIssue1.zip

Answer (score 0):

Implement IScheduler with ThreadPool of .NET, and set maximum threads of ThreadPool easily.

There are several implementations of ThreadPool on code project, You can use them if you are not

interested in default application pool of .NET or you might not like to use ThreadPool of .NET in

this situation

Let me know, If you have problem in implementing IScheduler itself.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you Yasser I will look up CodeProject. What is the disadvantage of .NET ThreadPool?, I hear a lot of people talking bad about it.

Comment: You could at least provide some links to support your findings.

Comment: I got my own IScheduler only to find out Rx is internally forcing a call to ScheduleLongRunning() which starts a new thread regardless of how my scheduler is written. :(

Comment: I'll answer you ASAP , but I'm away from my computer )-:
I'll replace this comment with my answer within 5 hours

Comment: Well, its been 13 hours. But I appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: I've searched a lot about custom RX ISceduler implementations.
But I couldn't find the solution for your problems in a easy way
Myabe my codes are different from your codes, so could you please provide me your sample code ?

Comment: This is what I am using [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) . Problem is not how IScheduler is programmed. Its the Rx which is ignoring it and using some special Trampoline logic which creates the separate thread.